# Binding events to list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm dynamically creating a list using JQuery and would like to bind each element to a "tap" event.  How would I do this?  Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do, but it isn't working.

```
for(var i=1; i <= 5; i++) {
        var id = "item" + i;
        var li = $("<li data-theme=\"d\" id=\"" + id + "\">Item " + i + "</li>");
        li.appendTo(ul);

        $(document).delegate("#"+id, "tap", function() {
            $("#"+id).attr({ "data-theme" : "e", "class" : "ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-e" });
        });
    }
```

This code triggers when tapping any element, however it always modifies the last element in the list for some reason.

Comment: I have a quick question. You're already _creating_ the items yourself. You have references to them. Why are you adding `data-theme` and setting an `id`? You can create an array of objects to back up your data, then have them reference the elements. That way you could separate concerns nicely, and you wouldn't need all this sort of voodoo.

Comment: Er good question, my code is kind of silly since I'm just messing around right now.  I'm adding a data-theme because I want to change the color of the list element when I tap it.

Comment: Data attributes are a horrible feature that driven into the spec by abusing people who have not heard of separation of concerns. Bad habits are hard to break - I strongly suggest you learn to do it right the first time. Would you be interested in seeing an alternative design not using data attributes or jQuery as an answer to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: For sure, I'm not quite sure I understood what you said but I definitely don't want to have any bad practices in my code. Could you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum what OP is trying to explain here is that he/she wants to use [jQuery Mobile's inbuilt themes](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/demos/faq/how-does-theming-work.php) dynamically . As you must know jQM operates that way. [They heavily use data-* for their stuff](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc3/docs/api/data-attributes.html). Since they're packaged as a CSS file with jQM downloan, not using this would be a waste of potential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**YOUR OPTIONS**

- Either move the event handling to outside the loop

  ```
  for(var i=1; i <= 5; i++) {
   ....
  }
  $(document).delegate("[id^=item]", "tap", function() {
  });
  ```
- Use the `bind` method and apply the `tap` event to the element, and not to the `document`.

  ```
  for(var i=1; i <= 5; i++) {
    //append li to ul
    $("#"+id).bind("tap", function() {
      $(this).attr({ 
            "data-theme" : "e", 
            "class" : "ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-e"   
      });
    });
  }
  ```
- BUT, the best way to be to put the `event` outside the loop, and bind the event to `ul` which will later delegate it to li.

  ```
  for(var i=1; i <= 5; i++) {
   ....
  }
  $("ul").delegate("[id^=item]", "tap", function() {
  });
  ```

**NOTE**

If you want to change your theme, you also need to update your layout once.

```
$("ul").delegate("[id^=item]", "tap", function() {
     $(this).attr({ 
              "data-theme" : "e", 
              "class" : "ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-e"   
     }).parent("ul").listview().listview("refresh");
});
```

**USE OF `STARTS WITH` SELECTOR**

You've put this in your code :

```
var id = "item" + i;
```

That means for the whole loop of 5 elements, your ids are gonna look like this :

```
<li id="item1">..
<li id="item2">..
<li id="item3">..
<li id="item4">..
```

Looking at the common thing here, I'd say it is :

```
item
```

So, since your ids start with `item` you could generalise it by using the [starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/). So,

```
id^=item
```

means that you're searching for elements with id that starts with `item`. And since its an attribute,

```
[id^=item]
```

**A MORE MODULAR APPROACH**

This method involves lesser HTML :

```
//your ul tag
var ul = $("ul")
//set up an array for adding li to it.
var li = [];
//a temporary element to store "li"
var $li;
for(var i=1; i <= 5; i++) {
    //add required attributes to the element
    var $li = $("<li/>", {
              "data-theme" : "d",
              "id" : "item" + i,
              "html" : "Item " + i
             });
    //push that into array
    li.push($li);
}
//wait for append to finish
ul.append(li).promise().done(function () {
  //wait for list to be added - thats why you wait for done() event in promise()
  //add the click events to this - event delegation - this way your click event is added only once 

  $(this).on("tap", "[id^=item]", function () {
     $(this).attr({ 
              "data-theme" : "e", 
              "class" : "ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-e"   
     }).parent("ul").listview().listview("refresh");
  });

  //then refresh
  $(this).listview().listview("refresh");    
});
```

Here's a demo for this : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/TdHXL/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great answer, this worked perfectly! Do you mind explaining how the [id*=item] selector works? I've never seen it formatted like that with the square brackets and *= operator.

Comment: Thanks boss, your answer definitely helped me the most!

Answer (score 1):

Just move the event handler to outside the for loop.

And replace

```
$(document).delegate("#"+id, "tap", function() {
```

with

```
$(document).delegate("[id*=item], "tap", function() {
```

**JS**

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var id = "item" + i;
    var li = $("<li data-theme=\"d\" id=\"" + id + "\">Item " + i + "</li>");
    li.appendTo(ul);
}

$(document).delegate("[id*=item]", "tap", function () {
    $("#" + id).attr({
        "data-theme": "e",
            "class": "ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-e"
    });
});
```

Comment: You're a wizard!  Thanks so much.  Do you mind explaining how the first argument ""[id*=item]" works?

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.

Comment: It is attribute contains selector.. It will match all the elements that contains `item` in the id attribute.. Check this out  .. Check this http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I'd do:

```
var items = []; // an actual JavaScript array - a list of items.

for(var i=1;i<=5;i++){
    items.push({theme:'d'}); //add an item to our list, 
                             //Anything that actually relates to the item should be
                             //here, text, other data and such. This is our 'view model'.
}

items.forEach(function(item,i){ // for each item, bind to the dom
    var el = document.createElement("li"); //create an element
    el.textContent = i+1; // set its text

    el.onclick = function(e){ // or ontap or whatever
        el.className = "ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-e";
        item.theme = "d";
    }//you mind want to use addEventListener instead at a later point

    item.el = el;
    ul.appendChild(el); // you need access to ul, currently being a jQuery object ul[0].
});
```

Note we have access to the items directly from our code, we can update them directly and such and have a direct reference to them. We don't need to *query our own data* - we *own* it and know directly how to get to it.

Also - we don't have a 80kb dependency.  No complex selectors, no 'magic' bindings. Everything is straight forward and it's just plain ol' javascript.

Note: forEach should be shimmed (easily) for older browsers.